# How to configure ASP.NET Core 3.1 application to run ReactJS and MVC website side by side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-routing

I have a ASP.NET core react website created with [CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/). The react application is for readonly public facing pages.

I also want to have some admin pages created as EF cores scaffolded Razor Pages, for example;

- https://localhost/robots - react application to show a list of robots to a user
- https://localhost/robots/admin - MVC application to show a list of robots and admin actions to a user

How can routing be configured to suit both situations?

Start up configuration is as follows;

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
            });

            services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbContext")));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "admin",
                    pattern: "admin/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    //spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                    spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:3000");
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `startup.cs` the endpoint mapping is configured for MVC. This can be made to work but it will be easier to change this;

Change

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "admin",
    pattern: "admin/{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

to

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Information learned from https://andrewlock.net/comparing-startup-between-the-asp-net-core-3-templates/ and https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing

Comment: @mausinc this never went to production it was for a proof of concept

Comment: Ah yes, i am having some problems running both mvc routes and spa in production. I will have to look further, thanks for replying.

Comment: My understanding is that this should work in any environment you host in. It worked when I uploaded to Azure Website. Are you using react-router by any chance?

Comment: I am using react-router yes

Comment: To reproduce

Add Mvc project (3.1) with React template in VS 2019.
Add HomeController and Index View
Development /Home/Index shows the MVC View as expected
Production only after ctrl+f5 (https://office365demo.azurewebsites.net/home/index)

Comment: Don't forget that routing for react (and most SPA) works very differently. You have to activate your react component before react-routes will work, this  is typically via your app.js or index.js entry point. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually

Comment: Yes, thanks. I need the catch all approach, serving the / to the dist folder, and /home to the mvc controller. I am surprised you had this working out of the box.